# Get array from object in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, getter

This question might be simple but I never use raw pointers or arrays in C++ so...

I need to use a library function which looks like this:

```
void f(double a[3][3], double b[3], double c[3]);
```

`a` and `b` are used for input and the result is stored in `c`.

The computation of `a` is a bit complex but does never change so it makes sense to calculate it only once and save the result. In my program, I can link it to an object of type `X`.

```
class X{
public:
X(){ 
    a = {{1,2,3},
         {4,5,6},
         {7,8,9}}; 
    }

private:
    double a[3][3];
}
```

How can I write a getter for `X::a` which can be used in function `f`?

This is how I would like to call function f:

```
#include "X.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    X o = X(); //create object
    double a[3][3] = o.getA(); // I want to get a somehow
    double b[3] =  {1,2,3}; // create dummy b
    double c[3] = {}; // create empty c
    f(a,b,c); // call funktion to populate c
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
        std::cout << c[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be missing some detail here, but in your snippet, you store `X` on the stack as well as `a`, and both are in the same scope. Why can't you just omit `X` and provide some function `computeA(double a[3][3])`?

Comment: I changed the example a bit. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: You can't return raw pointer array  from a function in C. You can return std::vector and get data(). In C int a[n] is equal int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n); free(a)

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Of course you can, `std::strdup` does. And no, the two declarations you’ve shown are **not** equal.

Comment: Sorry, but std::strdup returns char * it is not a char[5]

Comment: Mind you, `void f(double a[3][3], double b[3], double c[3]);` is exactly the same as `void f(double** a, double* b, double* c);`. Arrays get downgraded to pointers when passing them as arguments, so you are supposed to know it's size or pass the size together with array somehow.

Comment: @user7431005 Please post **correct**, **complete**, **minimal** code; the code you’ve shown doesn’t compile (even ignoring the issue you’re asking about) for a variety of reasons (e.g. missing types, missing semicolons).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Actually the parameter declaration `double a[3][3]` is equivalent to `double (*)[3]`, which makes it compatible with `A::a`.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Right, and that’s a “raw pointer” that points to an array.

Comment: @(Konrad Rudolph) Look at example in the man page  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup. You can find that you should call free(c). To free memory, therefore it is a dynamic allocated memory. c[n] - allocates memory on stack of function or class, therefore it is not safe to return pointers to c[n]. std::strdup returns pointer to dynamic allocated memory. It is main reason. I should comment my previous comment :). a[5] and  int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5); free(a) equivalent (or very similar for a client) if you call free in a same scope there you call malloc.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I know all that but it’s unrelated to what you said (and which I corrected). In fact, your new comment contains more errors: `T[n]` can allocate static memory, and you *can* return a pointer to that safely (though it’s not usually a good idea).

Comment: It seems unfriendly of the interface to demand a `double[3][3]` instead of a simple `**double`, which would resolve most of the problems. Is there a good reason not to do that, which I'm missing? The half-assed type checking of C-style function parameters can't be it, as e.g. `double[2][2]` would be fine for the compiler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is the way to go for 2D arrays in C++, but if you can't bypass the obstacle you are facing, then it would be possible to pass the matrix as a parameter to the getter function, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class X {
 public:
    void getA(double (&array)[3][3]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                array[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
 private:
    double a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},
            {4,5,6},
            {7,8,9}};
};

int main(void) {
    X o = X();
    double a[3][3];
    o.getA(a);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            std::cout << a[i][j] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than copying `X::a`, why not pass it directly?

Comment: Because X::a is allocated inside o and will die with o. It is not safe, because o will die then current scope will finish.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov `main::a` has the same lifetime as `main::o` (and `main::o.a`), they will die together.

Comment: @KonradRudolph what exactly are you saying? Passing a pointer for example?

Comment: @gsamaras Just make `X::a` public and pass `o.a` to `f`.

Comment: Data members are usually private @KonradRudolph. A pointer would a go for this, but using pointers in C++ require some wisdom, which the whole design seems to lack at the moment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes. In this example it is so. But for a real application, that has many threads and uses event base entering points in the code, it is not a good idea. It will be code with a bad smell. Exist one sign (of many) of good code: good code never returns a non const inner pointers without transfer a control over a life time of the point. If a code returns non const inner pointer it means that the code transfers the control over the pointer to the client. In my opinion, if you want to share a pointer, use one of common method for this task (shared_ptr or other)

Comment: @gsamaras Sure but in this case having a private data member makes no sense, and is actively detrimental. Real code should obviously do something completely different anyway.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph. asyncFunction(o->getA()); /*where const a* getA()*/ produces crash. Returns a inner pointer my be good. But For the question ("get array") and for async application it is not a best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should serve your purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    X() {
    }

    typedef double (*ptr_matrix)[3];

    ptr_matrix getA(){
        return a;
    }

private:
    double a[3][3] = {{ 1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9}};
};

void f(double a[3][3], double b[3], double c[3])
{
    cout<<"Inside f function";
    for(auto i = 0; i < 3;i++) {
        cout<<endl;
        for(auto j = 0 ; j < 3;j++)
            cout<<a[i][j];
    }
}

int main()
{
    X o = X(); //create object
    double (*a)[3] = NULL;
    a = o.getA(); // I want to get a somehow

    double b[3] = {0};
    double c[3] = {0};

    f(a,b,c);

}
```

Comment: Same comment as on the other answer: why copy the array?!

Comment: removed copying

Comment: I don’t think this code is much better: don’t pass results via arguments, use return values. I’m also not very happy by the aliasing of `double[3][3]` with `double*`, and you won’t be able to pass the result to OP’s `f` function without yet another cast.

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, `cout << a[i+j]` is a bug: the `i` is missing a `*3` to actually access `a[i][j]`

Comment: This is cleanest way I could do.